# Spurious space on moderncv \cventry using \if

Tags: spacing, conditionals, moderncv

I am trying to display some information in a `\cventry` conditionally using a defined `\ifdetails` switch. However, for some reason that is beyond my knowledge, an spurious space (or new line) is created.

I tested this using `\newtoggle` from `etoolbox` and the same happens. Not sure if it has to do with the definition of the `\cventry` itself, or with the conditionals as macros.

Also, notice the strange behavior on the `\ifdetails`. If I put a `%` to protect the change of line after the brace, I need to `\protect` the `\ifdetails`. However, if I don't put that `%` it is not required.

Can someone explain what is the problem? And how can I eliminate the spurious white space?

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\newif\ifdetails
%\detailstrue
\detailsfalse

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}
\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{
\ifdetails% if not using a % before, I don't need to protect
I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. 
\fi
}
\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{%<- if using this, I need to \protect below
\protect\ifdetails%
I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
% This more complex content breaks existing solutions
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\fi%
}

\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

**Edit:** I added the `itemize` environment on the contents to show that it breaks solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for checking an empty argument within [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)'s `\cventry` is not appropriate. Here's the definition:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

The check on argument `#7` uses `\ifx&#7&%` to see whether `#7` is empty. Instead, use a test mechanism from [Safe test for an empty expanded macro argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212740/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\newif\ifdetails
%\detailstrue
\detailsfalse

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\long\noexpand\def\noexpand\argseven{#7}}\x
    \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\argseven}\relax %\ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}
\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{%
\ifdetails 
I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. 
\fi
}
\cventry{year--year}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}{THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}{THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}{AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}{
\ifdetails
I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important. %
\fi%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to revive this question, but I just noticed that when using `\detailstrue` and the `%` after the opening brace, the code doesn't work. And if one does not uses the `%` then a spurious space appears. Any thoughts?

Comment: @adn: With `\detailstrue` and no `%` after the opening brace (not in the definition, but in the `\cventry` use), I don't get a spurious space.

Comment: I get this error: "`! Incomplete \if; all text was ignored after line 28.
<inserted text> 
                \fi`"

Comment: @adn: [Here's a MWE](http://pastebin.com/fN89Ux0c) that doesn't provide any problems, so you see what I mean.

Comment: That works, but if you put a `%` after the brace it doesn't. (Like [this one](http://pastebin.com/q0exGcdy))

Comment: @adn: See the updated answer [revision](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/247329/revisions). I've grouped `#7` in the `\if` condition to avoid mis-interpretation of the `\fi` in `\ifdetails`...`\fi`.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. It didn't occur to me to group it. Another trick learned. Thanks! :)

Comment: After more testing, when using brackets around #7 and when details are false, it doesn't detect it as empty and add a newline.

Comment: @adn: I'll look into this...

Comment: @adn: Try the updated suggestion with `\argseven`...

Comment: With simple text it works as intended. However, when using complex content it breaks. For example, if you put an `itemize` environment with the details it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Where you able to check it with the `itemize`?

Comment: @adn: Yes, but I don't have a solution. My suggestion would be to minimize the problem (since it's probably unrelated to [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)) and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why the sixth mandatory argument is not evaluated to empty; I'll reformat the code for better reading.

Your code can be equivalently written

```
\cventry{year--year}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}
  {THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}
  {AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}
  {
   \ifdetails
     I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
     The "year-year" is not important. 
   \fi
  }
```

and there is a space after the opening brace of the sixth argument. So, even if the conditional was ignored, the argument would not be empty. But the conditional is *not* ignored.

The definition of `\cventry` does `\ifx&#7&` and with your input this becomes

```
\ifx& \ifdetails...\fi&
```

which is evaluated to false, because TeX compares `&` with a space. However, protecting the end-of-line with `%` would not solve the problem: with

```
\cventry{year--year}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}
  {THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}
  {AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}
  {%
   \ifdetails
     I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
     The "year-year" is not important. 
   \fi
  }
```

TeX would execute

```
\ifx&\ifdetails...\fi&
```

and it would compare `&` with `\ifdetails`, which returns false as well. The problem is that TeX does not expand tokens when it is absorbing arguments.

A possible redefinition, using `expl3` facilities, is

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cventry}{O{.25em}mmmmmm}
 {
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}
   {
    {\bfseries#3}
    \tl_if_blank:nF{#4}{,~{\slshape#4}}
    \tl_if_blank:nF{#5}{,~#5}
    \tl_if_blank:nF{#6}{,~#6}
    .\strut
    \tl_if_blank:fF{#7}
     {
      \newline\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_blank:nF { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\ifdetails
%\detailstrue
\detailsfalse

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}

\cventry{year--year}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}
  {THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}
  {AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}
  {\ifdetails 
     I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
     The "year-year" is not important. 
   \fi}

\detailstrue
\cventry{year--year}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, AS YOU CAN PLAINLY SEE}
  {THIS IS ALSO JUSTIFIED}
  {THIS IS JUSTIFIED, TOO}
  {AND THIS IS JUSTIFIED AS WELL}
  {\ifdetails
     I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
     The "year-year" is not important.
   \fi}

\end{document}
```

I suggest you to adopt this format, that makes it easier to check the number of arguments: six is a large number and I remember some questions on the site where the issue was precisely having forgotten some of them.

Note that `\ifdetails` should follow the brace or `%` should be used if you prefer a format such as

```
  {%
   \ifdetails
     I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
     The "year-year" is not important.
   \fi
  }
```