# Robust handler of arguments with conditionals and complex elements

Tags: conditionals, expansion, arguments

## Context

This question is a follow up of [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247329/7561) of this question [Spurious space on moderncv \cventry using \if](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247322/spurious-space-on-moderncv-cventry-using-if/247329?noredirect=1#comment617824_247329)

## Problem

The problem is that complex content (for example, `itemize` on the content of the argument) is not handled well when the conditional is set to true.

## Emulation

To emulate and show the problem, I created the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdetails
\detailstrue
%\detailsfalse

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{-#1-}
\newcommand{\wrapper}[1]{%
\test{%
\begingroup
\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
\noexpand\long\noexpand\def\noexpand\argseven{#1}}\x
\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\argseven}\relax 
\else{#1}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\wrapper{%
\ifdetails 
I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however. The "year-year" is not important.
\fi
}

\wrapper{%
\ifdetails
I would like all this stuff to be raggedright, however.
% This more complex content breaks existing solutions
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\fi%
}

\end{document}
```

When one executes that with `\detailsfalse` the code works. However, with `\detailstrue` there is an error:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \itemize ...nce \@itemdepth \@ne \edef
>   \@itemitem 
>                                                     {labelitem\romannumeral \t...

## Question

Thus, what is the correct way of handling the argument, so that the `\if` inside can be evaluated, as well as the complex content on it. (Like the problem of the question [Spurious space on moderncv \cventry using \if](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247322/spurious-space-on-moderncv-cventry-using-if/247329?noredirect=1#comment617824_247329))

Comment: `\begin` and `\item` are fragile, so they don't survive `\protected@edef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit I don't fully understand what you're trying to do here, but as egreg notes, `\begin` and `\item` are fragile which is what's causing the problem. It's easy enough to "fix" this particular example

```
\newcommand{\wrapper}[1]{%
    \test{%
        \begingroup
        \let\begin\relax
        \let\item\relax
        \let\end\relax
        \protected@edef\x{%
            \endgroup
            \noexpand\long\noexpand\def\noexpand\argseven{#1}%
        }%
        \x
        \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\argseven}\relax\else
            #1%
        \fi
    }%
}
```

I don't understand what the point of that conditional is (and I removed the braces around `#1`).

Since you're using `\detokenize`, you're relying on e-TeX, so you can use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\begin
\robustify\end
\robustify\item
```

to make those robust. And assuming that the conditional is to check if `\argseven` is blank, you can use `\ifblank{#1}{true branch}{false branch}` from `etoolbox`.