# Ifx and end of line

Tags: line-breaking, conditionals

Can anyone shed some light on this? I have an interesting problem involving the "There's no line here to end" error.

EDIT: Variables. I did not think to include this as I thought there was only one way to declare variables.

```
\newcommand{\@emptymacro}{}% Used to test against an empty macro


\newcommand{\@name}{}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\renewcommand{\bfseries \@name{#1}}}

\newcommand{\@descr}{}
\newcommand{\descr}[1]{\renewcommand{\itshape \@descr{#1}}}


\newcommand{\@note}{}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\renewcommand\@note{#1}}
```

I have the following command defined, which works under the most common use case.

```
\newcommand{\makenamedentry}{
    \ifx\@name\@emptymacro
    \else
        {\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries \@name}\\ % print the entry name
        \vspace{1.5pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt}
    \fi
    \ifx\@descr\@emptymacro
    \else
        {\@descr} % print description
    \fi

    \ifx\@note\@emptymacro
    \else
        {\@note} % print note
    \fi
}
```

Here is the most common implementation. The key being that it is named.

```
\name{My Name}
\descr{My Descr}
\note{My Note}
\makenamedentry
```

I recently tried to use this for a one off case, without a name. It caused the "There's no line here to end" error.

```
\name{}
\descr{My Descr}
\note{My Note}
\makenamedentry
```

With some testing I noticed that this however does not have the error. Unfortunately this is an unacceptable solution for me as it is to complicated to explain to those I have useing the end product. So I need to figure out why I am getting the error in the first place.

```
% used line, either comment or paragraph
\name{}
\descr{My Descr}
\note{My Note}
\makenamedentry
```

Now I think it has to do with the `\\` on line 4 of the `newcommand`, as that is the only end of line character. What I do not understand is why it is trying to execute under the case when no name is provided. Perhaps the `\\` exists outside the normal logic structure? I am not sure.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ANSWER BELOW THIS LINE----------------------------

I have edited this post to make the solution more clear.

While the question was about ifx, the reason I was having problems was because my test for emptiness was bad. This was making my code run the `\else` case (I write all my logic inverted) even when I thought I was not.

The reason being that \name{} was not the samething as `\name{null}`. Why that is I am not sure, also why `\@emptymacro` is null when `\name{}` is not I also cannot say. Regardless my solution was construct `\@emptymacro` the same way as `\@name`. For the record I write just about everything inside a .cls file so these commands do work. Something about the `@` character breaks them if you take them out as it is a reserved character. If you want to implement them yourself you can simply rename the `\@` to `\at`.

```
\newcommand{\@emptymacro}{}% Used to test against an empty macro
\newcommand{\emptymacro}[1]{\renewcommand\@emptymacro{#1}}
\emptymacro{}

\newcommand{\@name}{}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\renewcommand\@name{#1}}

\newcommand{\@note}{}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\renewcommand\@note{#1}}

\newcommand{\@descr}{}
\newcommand{\descr}[1]{\renewcommand\@descr{#1}}
```

By having them expand to the same thing this makes me able to test using ifx (which is defined here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/ifx)

Comment: Please, make a complete compilable example. In particular it's important to know how `\name` and `\@emptymacro` are defined.

Comment: No need for `{..}` around the true or false “arguments”.

Comment: @Manuel It depends on how `\desc` and `\note` are defined.

Comment: I have some suspects, but without a complete example, it's just guessing.

Comment: I guess that @egreg guesses that `\empty@macro` is defined with `\def` and `\@name` is defined with `\newcommand` (or the other way round)

Comment: Unrelated but the space added by `\vspace` will come between the first and second lines of the `\descr` (or after a one line `\descr`) is that intended?

Comment: Are you sure David? It seems to put it between the `\name` and `\descr`. I played with that value to get the spaceing right.

Comment: Your test for "emptiness" is not good (fails with an empty space in the argument, for example). I'd use  `\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\@name}\relax`

Comment: For testing an empty argument, see [Safe test for an empty expanded macro argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212740/5764) or [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764).

Comment: I found my problem I think. `\name{}` was not the samething as `\name{null}`. Why that is I am not sure, also why `\@emptymacro` is null is another question.

Comment: @Bob I asked for a complete example for a reason. You don't want to show it: of course `\newcommand{\name}[1]{\renewcommand{\bfseries \@name{#1}}}` is code that cannot possibly work, so it is definitely *not* part of a complete example.

Comment: Now, the code in the Overleaf project you link to doesn't show the issue. So what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\ifx` is working in your code. If you don't provide the MWE where the error occurs than we cannot guessing anything.

But your code includes many LaTeX misunderstandings. I rewrite your result to TeX primitives in order to more clear understand what happened.

(1) When name is nonempty, then the result is:

```
\indent NAME\hfil\break
\vadjust{\vskip1.5 pt plus.5pt minus.5pt}\space DESCRIPTION \par

\indent NOTE
```

The `\hfil\break` ends the first line of the paragraph where NAME is (this is roughly speaking the expansion of `\\` macro). The second line of paragraph starts with `\vadjust` (this is roughly speaking the expansion of `\vspace` macro). The `\vadjust` command puts the space *after the second line of paragraph*, it means between first and second line of DESCRIPTION. If the DESCRIPTION is only one line long then vertical space will be after the paragraph.
The paragraph is ended at the end of DESCRIPTION (TeX inserts `\par` at the empty line in your code). Finally new paragraph starts with NOTE.

Note that if you have `\parindent` nonzero, then you get indentation before NAME and NOTE, but no indentation before DESCRIPTION. Only one space is before DESCRIPTION (it comes from the end of your line where `\vspace` is used).

Note that the second paragraph is not finalized. It means that if you type

```
\makenamedentry 
something more`
```

then the text `something more` will be appended to the second paragraph at the same line where the NOTE is.

(2) When the NAME is empty then you get:

```
\indent DESCRIPTION\par

\indent NOTE
```

Simple two paragraphs are here. But the second paragraph is not ended, of course.

I guess that you needs something like this:

```
\newtoks\name \newtoks\descr \newtoks\note
\def\makenamedentry{\par
    {\bf \the\name}\par
    \ifx^\the\name^\else \vskip 1.5pt plus.5pt minus.5pt \fi
    \the\descr\par
    \the\note\par
}

\name{My Name}
\descr{This is a description}
\note{some note}
\makenamedentry
```

Comment: When I post questions I always try to trim down the parts in order to make it focus only on the parts I have questions about. In this case I have accidentally solved my issue in making it simpler. I have edited my initial post to show a change on the variable declaration. Notice how name turns the characters bold. I have found my issue, here is a working example https://www.overleaf.com/3240936mmngtz.

Comment: Although my `vspace` seems to work fine. Wouldnt `\name` and `\descr` be the same paragraph? Making `\descr` the second line?