# How does \if actually get used?

Tags: conditionals, learning

I apologize if this is too newbie or a duplicate, but I've banged my head against it long enough, and searched without success. :(

I am trying to use an `\if` to test for an empty string without success and have traced it to my understanding of the `\if` itself.  I have added sample code showing how I'm misusing `\if` in a real simple way:

```
\def\tmpOne{hello}
\tmpOne %shows that \tmpOne produces hello
\if{\tmpOne}{hello}
goodbye %This is never reached.
\fi
```

Closer to my actual application is:

```
\newcount\tmpInd

\def\funcOne{%
\advance\tmpInd by 1 
\if{\testEmpty{\readHistory{\value\tmpInd}}}{<NOT EMPTY>}
\funcOne
\fi
}   
%where \testEmpty returns either <EMPTY> or <NOT EMPTY>
%and \readHistory is my own previously defined function
%(They work as expected outside of this context)
```

Any help for my obviously weak understanding would be appreciated. :)

Edit:
Due to information in one of the comments, I have added some extra details of my particular use case...

The definition for `\testEmpty` is:

```
\newcommand{\testEmpty}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd0=0pt<EMPTY>\else<NOT EMPTY>\fi}
```

The definition for `\readHistory` is:

```
\newcommand{\readHistory}[1]{\getdata[#1]\myChangeHistory}
```

The definition for `\getData` is:

```
\def\getdata[#1]#2{\csname data:\string#2:#1\endcsname}
```

The data is stored with `\storeData`:

```
\def\storedata#1#2{\tmpnum=0 \edef\tmp{\string#1}\storedataA#2\end\expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:0\endcsname{\tmpcnt}}
\def\storedataA#1{\advance\tmpnum by1
\ifx\end#1\else
  \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\tmpnum\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\storedataA\fi
}
```

Note: I have patched these together by trawling the internet, and only partly understand them (but they all do what I want).

Comment: [This wiki has some not-yet-outdated information.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Conditionals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is doomed to failure. The conditional `\if` tests character code equality of the next two *unexpandable* tokens it finds after it, performing expansion until unexpandable tokens remain. So

```
\if{\tmpOne}{hello} goodbye \fi
```

sees `{`, which is unexpandable and then expands `\tmpOne`; after this expansion the input stream is

```
\if{hello}{hello} goodbye \fi
```

and, since `{` and `h` aren't the same unexpandable token as far as `\if` is concerned (their character codes differ), the conditional returns false and TeX ignores everything up to the first matching `\else` or `\fi`. No `\else` is found, so what remains is

```
\fi
```

which has empty expansion; next TeX goes on.

Without knowing more about `\readHistory` it's impossible to suggest alternative strategies.

Comment: Thanks for responding...   If I understand the terminology correctly, \testEmpty expands to either "<EMPTY>" or "<NOT EMPTY>", depending on the expansion of \readHistory{3}.  Therefore \if will always end up comparing < and E or < and N.  Is that correct?  (Assuming I get rid of the braces {})

Comment: @SeanCooper It much depends on those macros are defined. A token list not producing output is not necessarily empty.

Comment: Thanks... I have updated the main question to include several layers of definition. ...

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but it seems I need to adjust things to indicate "empty" vs. "not empty" with a single character and get the functions to expand before comparison?

Comment: @SeanCooper no. Your  `\testempty` does not work by expansion (and does not test if its argument is empty) the first non expandable token in its expansion is `\setbox` so the `\if` in your code always tests `{` against `\setbox` and is therefore always false and skips to the `\fi`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ...  I hear what you are saying... but it doesn't behave that way in practice.  In actual practice it works as intended.  It does NOT always evaluate false. :)

Edit: It occurred to me that you might be refering to the if statement refering to \testempty rather than the \testempty itself.  If that is the case, I withdraw the comment. :P  I will look into that.

Comment: @SeanCooper yes `\if{\testempty` is `\if{\setbox`  and that is always false. `\testempty` doesn't test if its argument is empty but if it has zero width so `\testempty{\rlap{hello}}` would typeset (not expand to) `<EMPTY>`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ...  I have tested what you said about \rlap{hello} and you are correct.  \testEmpty as written works for what I've been using it for, but clearly there are failure cases.  If you have the time/interest I would love to hear an explanation, because I'm not sure I understand why it does that or how to correct for it if it becomes a problem later. :)

Answer (score 1):

I marked egreg's answer as accepted, because it actually answered the question as written.

I ended up solving the problem a slightly different way and am posting this answer in case it benefits anyone else.

I ended up using a \newif.

```
\newif\iftestEmptyBool
\newcommand{\testEmpty}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd0=0pt \testEmptyBooltrue\else \testEmptyBoolfalse\fi}

\newcounter{tmpind}
\setcounter{tmpind}{0}
\def\funcOne{\addtocounter{tmpind}{1}\testEmpty{\readHistory{\thetmpind}}\iftestEmptyBool\else\funcOne\fi}
```

The \testEmpty is now run beforehand and \iftestEmptyBool is used as the conditional.

Comment: testempty is explicitly testing the width of the argument when typeset so there are lots of none empty arguments that would show as empty. To see better tests see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212740/safe-test-for-an-empty-expanded-macro-argument