# replace Table emtpy cells

Tags: tables

I'd like to know how one can change the table's default empty cell space to something else when the cell has nothing written in it.

E.g:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
& x & x
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Would result in this:

```
1|2|3|4
 |x|x|
```

But what I'm aiming for is to replace the blank cell for, let's say, 0.
So something like this:

```
1|2|3|4
0|x|x|0
```

Thanks.

-- Edit --

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
& x & x
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell why you need it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the `collcell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{F}[1]{>{\collectcell\fillempty}#1<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand{\fillempty}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    0%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{F{l}} }
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  & x & x &   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & y & y
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The third row shows two features: the first is that with `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` you can override the filling; the second is that if you don't have an explicit empty cell, the filling is *not* performed, because TeX doesn't add trailing cells on a row.

[image]

See [What does \ifx\\#1\\ stand for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33823/what-does-ifx-1-stand-for) for the `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` trick.