# Am I using etoolbox correctly for string comparison?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, comparison

I have a little environment to enumerate question statements. Sometimes, I want the label to not be a number but some string instead. In that case, I do not want the counter to be incremented.

```
% question environment
\newcounter{QuestionCounter}
\stepcounter{QuestionCounter}
\newenvironment{question}[1][\arabic{QuestionCounter}] {
  \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}
  \noindent\textbf{Question #1. }\ignorespaces
  \ifdefstrequal{#1}{\value{QuestionCounter}}
  {\stepcounter{QuestionCounter}}
  {}}{}
```

The concerning `if-statement` here being,

```
\ifdefstrequal{#1}{\value{QuestionCounter}}
{\stepcounter{QuestionCounter}}
{}
```

How can I compare the value (expansion?) of the argument `#1` and the value of the counter `\value{QuestionCounter}`? I have tried `\ifdefstrequal{\value{#1}}{\value{QuestionCounter}}` because I thought `\ifdefstrequal` first two arguments need to be macros.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's incorrect usage. And you'd need to do test with full expansion.

I'd do it in a different way: *if* the optional argument is missing (or empty), the counter is stepped and used for numbering the question.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{QuestionCounter}
\newenvironment{question}[1][]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \stepcounter{QuestionCounter}%
    \thisquestion{\arabic{QuestionCounter}}%
  \else
    \thisquestion{#1}%
  \fi
 }{%
  \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
 }
\newcommand{\thisquestion}[1]{%
  \noindent\textbf{Question #1. }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Is this a numbered question?
\end{question}

\begin{question}[foo]
Is this a numbered question?
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Is this a numbered question?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mind explaining how `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` checks for a lack of optional argument?

Comment: @scribe See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33826/4427 The default value for the optional argument is empty; if no optional argument is specified, `\detokenize{#1}` returns nothing and the test `\if\relax\relax` returns true. Otherwise `\detokenize{#1}` will deliver something that cannot start with `\relax`, so the test `\if\relax<something>` returns false and the rest of the string disappears as part of the “true text”.