# Are there more to applications of \iftrue and \iffalse?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, exercises

While reading "TeX for the impatient" on the topics of iftrue and iffalse, I encountered this example,

```
\def\isbigger{\let\bigger=\iftrue}
\def\isnotbigger{\let\bigger=\iffalse}
\def\test#1#2{\ifnum #1>#2 \isbigger \else \isnotbigger \fi}

\test{3}{6} \bigger$3>6$\else$3\le6$\fi \par
```

thinking I can do better than that, as shown below

```
\def\true#1#2{$#1>#2$}
\def\false#1#2{$#1\le#2$}
\def\test#1#2{\ifnum #1>#2 \true#1#2 \else \false#1#2 \fi}

\test{3}{6} \par
\test{6}{3} \par.
```

But wait, the book example, I wonder, may have an unsound signal(s) burried in it which I did not notice. So I explored and located this (What is iffalse for [What is \iffalse for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46377/34618)), addressed in
to find a direction leading to newif command, thus continuing my try of what follows

```
\newif\ifbigger
\def\test#1#2{\ifnum #1>#2 \biggertrue \else \biggerfalse \fi
\ifbigger$3>6$\else$3\le6$\fi}
\test{3}{6} \par
\test{6}{3} \par.
```

Satisfied with the exercies tried, I still have some concerns. Is this the burried signal I am looking for? Are there other directions that the shown programming techniques in the book are useful/crucial?

Comment: I don't understand. What does "unsound" or "buried signals" mean?

Comment: What I tried to say is that my code, in my view, can achieve the same results as those in the book. Is there an untold story on when to use \iftrue or \iffalse notion for that example on page 239? What are the focus/situation of using \iftrue or \iffalse?

Comment: After `\newif\ifbigger`, `\biggertrue` and `\biggerfalse` are just `\let\ifbigger=\iftrue` and `\let\ifbigger=\iffalse`, so the third code is exactly the same as the first one.

Comment: @egreg -- Is it fair to say that one should avoid using \iftrue or \iffalse because \newif technique is sufficient?

Comment: @Jesse `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` can sometimes get handy, but in general the `\newif` abstraction is better.

Comment: @egreg -- Would it be asking too much if you could enlighten me with one handy case addressed in the formal answer block so that I can learn from. Please.

Comment: @Jesse For an example, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46384/4427

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your original example is somewhat odd. The idea behind it is to define a new command `\bigger` which you can use in subsequent tests. The *whole point* is that `\bigger` is separate from `\test`, so your second example doesn't replicate its functionality.
The reason I call it ‘odd’ is that the code

```
\bigger
  % true code
\else
  % false code
\fi
```

doesn't quite ring true to me — but I'm long accustomed to seeing such conditionals begin with `\if…`.

The `\bigger` definition code is how `\newif` works internally, which you've now discovered. For what you're interested in, it's a reasonable approach to take. You may, however, be interested in alternative approaches (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5896/179). In terms of traps to be aware of, it can be better to avoid using `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` in general (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2951/179).

Comment: thanks for the speedy response and directions. Oh, just to clarify, the odd code is from the book which indeed puzzles me too, but it works.