# macro to replace \text{Subst} with \operatorname{Subst}?

Tags: macros, math-operators

Some latex that is autogenerated by Mathematica has this in it  `\text{Subst}` as part of much longer latex.

Is there a way to write a macro to replace `\text{Subst}` with `\operatorname{Subst}` that I can put in the preamble? I do not know how to use `\renewcommand`  to do this. It will be exactly `\text{Subst}` and nothing else that I want changed. i.e. no other `\text{stuff}`.

The reason I want to change it, is that it looks little better as an operator. There are so many of these in many files, so using the editor is not practical.

I can change in in Mathematica itself using string replacements pattern, but I thought it will be better to use Latex macro if possible.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\text{Subst}}{\operatorname{Subst}}%does not work
\begin{align*} 
y &= -2 \text{Subst}\left(\int \frac{1}{(3+x)^2} \, dx,x\right)
\end{align*}

%want the above to become as follows

\begin{align*} 
y &= -2 \operatorname{Subst}\left(\int \frac{1}{(3+x)^2} \, dx,x\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I looked at few questions, but could not figure how to do it.

TL 2020

Comment: Mathematica has `TeXForm` for that. It is IMHO much easier to tell Mathematica to make this an `\operatorname` when you export it from Mathematica. In general, `TeXForm` can really greatly help avoiding headache. (My head aches because of the italic differential `d`. Please use `\mathrm{d}x`.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, I know I could do it in Mathematica. This is output of `TeXForm` already. But I do not know how to tell `TeXForm` to only change this specific case to operatorname. I do not want to change all `\text{...}` to `\operatorname{...}`, only this one. But I can still do it in mathematica, using string change if needed. Just thought Latex macros can also do this, but was not sure.

Comment: In general LaTeX is comparably bad at arbitrary string manipulation (in particular outside the scope of a suitable macro). I guess you could use LuaTeX to replace occurrences of `\text{Subst}` on the fly or you could redefine `\text` in a way that makes `\text` auto-detect if its argument is `Subst` and switch to `\operatorname` in that case. But it is not clear whether those two options would be acceptable for you (not everyone wants to use LuaTeX; the `\text` auto-detection sounds like a bad hack). I think the best way is to tell Mathematica to produce the right TeX code.

Comment: @moewe so in Latex, the command `\renewcommand` is only to change the command name to another name, and not to to change `\command{agument}` to another `\command{argument}`. In this case, no problem, I can easily change it in Mathematica before writing it to file with string replace command. Thanks.

Comment: I think the Mathematica community has a solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153908). It does yield `\operatorname` commands. I agree with @moewe.

Comment: @Nasser You could use `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrequal` inside a redefinition of `\text`, but as others said, this sounds ugly (this wouldn't work if `\text` is redefined by `amsmath` environment mid-document, but I doubt this is the case). This way would not require LuaTeX.

Comment: To be honest. I think hacking `\text` is not at all a good idea. If you *really* want all occurrences of `\text{Subst}` to become `\operatorname{Subst}`, any text editor replaces this much faster than you copy any TeX solution in the document. Chances are you do not want to replace all of them and/or the TeX solution breaks (for instance because the arXiv has another version of `expl3`, say). Or one of you collaborators has the same great idea of also hacking `\text`, and the hacks clash. Let just Mathematica do it, much better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly. `\renewcommand` redefines what the macro does with its argument. It is possible to check 'string equality' with the input, so you could in theory redefine `\text` to branch behaviour on whether or not the input is `Subst`. But that has a few caveats that have to do with how TeX handles text/strings.

Comment: thanks to everyone for the good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot get Mathematica to output `\operatorname{Subst}` instead of `\text{Subst}` and if you're free to use LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you. It performs pattern matches and replaces all instances of `\text{Subst}` in the input file with `\operatorname{Subst}` "on the fly". The substitution operation is assigned to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback and therefore operates *before* TeX starts its usual processing operations (such as macro expansion). Observe that the `\text` macro is *not* redefined or modifed in any way.

I would further like to suggest that you load the `mleftright` package and use `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right`. This will improve (*viz.*, reduce) the amount of whitespace between "Subst" and the large opening parenthesis.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
\luaexec{
function Subst ( s )
  return (s:gsub ( "\\text{Subst}" , "\\operatorname{Subst}" ))
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", Subst , "Subst" ) 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
y &= -2 \text{Subst}\mleft(\int \frac{1}{(3+x)^2} \, dx,x\mright) \\
  &= -2 \operatorname{Subst}\mleft(\int \frac{1}{(3+x)^2} \, dx,x\mright)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

It would be *much* better if the code has the proper markup, not relying on fragile post-processing.

However, since `\operatorname` only accepts “safe” characters (no accents unless a Unicode engine is used) you can get away by redefining `\text`.

I also use `expl3` so the string-switch functions are already available.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% save the meaning of \text
\LetLtxMacro{\AMStext}{\text}

% now redefine \text
\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand{\text}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {Subst}{\operatorname{Subst}}
    {Foo}{\operatorname{\mathbf{Foo}}}
    % ...
   }
   {\AMStext{#1}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\itshape

This is an operator $x\text{Subst}(y)$

This is also an operator $y\text{Foo}$

This is text $a\text{baz}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if you work on a joint project and your collaborators have independently the idea of hacking an as basic command as `\text`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Well, one of the collaborators has to yield. Reread my first paragraph, please.

Comment: Just for the records: I have seen such hacks going terribly wrong. I most strongly recommend not to hack basic commands.  All one has to do is to do a trivial search and replace on the editor to have the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

*I recommend to have Mathematica not write `\text` or `\operatorname` but write some "placeholder-control-sequence" which in LaTeX and in packages used by many usually is not defined.  This way you are free to define that placeholder-control-sequence in the preamble/wherever according to your liking without the need of overriding/overloading/redefining control-sequences that are already defined/in use for whatever purposes where they should not be redefined.*

*Be that as it may:*

You can patch the `\text`-command to check whether its argument consists exactly of the token-sequence `S11`, `u11`, `b11`, `s11`, `t11`.

As `\text` is defined "robust" you actually need to patch the command whose name is `\text⟨space⟩`.

In the example below the check is implemented by means of a macro which processes delimited arguments rather than by defining temporary macros and doing `\ifx`-comparison. This way you don't have LaTeX (re)define temporary macros whenever `\text` is carried out. This in turn might save some of LaTeX's memory when `\text` is used more often.

With the delimited argument the phrase passed in as argument by the user is nested between exclamation-marks (`!`)/between something that does not occur within the phrase `Subst`. Then checking is done on the phrase `!Subst!`.  This way you can crank out the case of the phrase passed in as argument by the user containing `!` (and thus differing from the phrase `Subst`) before doing the checking by means of a `!Subst!`-delimited argument. Cranking out this case is needed in order to ensure that the phrase passed in as argument by the user does not consist of a set of tokens differing from the delimiter `!Subst!` but nevertheless containing and therefore matching that delimiter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% This macro is explained in detail in:
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522506/118714>
%% (The name given to it in that explanation is \CheckWhetherEmpty.)
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToExclam{\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@SubstFork{%
  \long\def\UD@SubstFork#1!Subst!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherSubst[3]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
    \UD@SubstFork
    !#1!{ #2}% Case: #1 = Subst
    !Subst!{ #3}% Case: #1 is empty or something else without ! 
    !!!!%
  }{ #3}% Case: #1 is something else with ! 
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Patch the command \text:
%% \text is robust, so actually the command \text<space> needs to be patched.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@Saved@Command@text{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\UD@Saved@Command@text\expandafter=\csname text \endcsname
}%
\long\@namedef{text }#1{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherSubst{#1}{\operatorname}{\UD@Saved@Command@text}{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
y &= -2 \text{Subst}\left(\int \frac{1}{(3+x)^2} \, dx,x\right)\\
  &= -2 \operatorname{Subst}\left(\int \frac{1}{(3+x)^2} \, dx,x\right)\\
  &\operatorname{Subst}&(\text{produced by {\tt\string\operatorname\{Subst\}}})\\
  &\text{Subst}&(\text{{\tt\string\operatorname}-variant produced by {\tt\string\text\{Subst\}}})\\
  &\text{Subst\empty}&(\text{{\tt\string\text}-variant produced by {\tt\string\text\{Subst\string\empty\}}})\\
  &\text{!Subst!}\\
  &\text{SubstSubst}\\
  &\text{Some bla bla}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can save the original meaning of `\text` to `\origtext` and then define `\text` as a macro which tests its argument if it is the "Subst":

```
\let\origtext=\text
\def\Subst{Subst}
\protected\def\text#1{\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\tmp\Subst 
   \expandafter \operatorname \else \expandafter \origtext \fi{#1}}
```

Comment: Try to see what happens if you happen to have `\section{$\text{Subst}$}`.

Comment: @wipet Let me say that with the original definition `$\text{\def\tempa#1{Text#1}\tempa{phrase}}$` does not yield `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \tmp.`  ;-)   But I would consider this less of a daily-usage-problem and more of a moot thing :-) .  Perhaps `\edef\tmp{\unexpanded{#1}}` instead of `\def\tmp{#1}`...

Comment: @UlrichDiez Maybe, more robust should be `\edef\Subst{\detokenized{Subst}}` and `\edef\tmp{\detokenized{#1}}` because we don't know the catcode value of `S` (for example) when `\text{Subst}` is scanned from the file. But I keep simple solution in my answer.

Comment: @egreg I am surprised that LaTeX 2020 does not use immediately expanded section mark (like 2.4), asynchronusly expanded `\the\pageno` and most important: `\unexpanded` or `\detokenized` title when it is writing to the aux file. Is is still fiddling with `\protect` context-dependent macro and control sequences finished by space in its name? How long we have `\unexpanded` and `\detokenized` TeX primitives?

Comment: @Wipet On the other hand: Does a user who , e.g., switches catcode of `S` to 1 and catcode of `t` to 2 really want her/his user-input `Subst` to be considered equal to the textual-phrase `Subst` rather than equal to something like `{ubs}`?  `;-)  To be honest: I don't see a silver bullet for handling all edge cases, therefore: Yes, the simpler the solution, the better. I mentioned the problem with user-input containing temporary definitions with arguments/hashes because - regardless considerations of catcodes etc - hashes/defining temporary macros is possible with the original definition.