# Check for empty tex file to decide ifthenelse branch

Tags: macros, expansion, ifthenelse

**Objective:**

I am trying to key on on the presence of file content (comments are acceptable, I am trying to key in on content that would be displayed in the built PDF) to determine what path to take.

If a .tex file has displayable content, perform ActionA.  If the .tex file is effectively empty (comments and blank lines only), perform ActionB.

**What I have:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\isFileEmpty}[1]{
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt%
    \boolean{true}%
  \else
    \boolean{false}%
  \fi
}

\CatchFileDef\filecontent{catchfile}{}%

Macro test line: \isFileEmpty\expandafter{\filecontent }

\ifthenelse{\isFileEmpty\expandafter{\filecontent }}%   <-- This is where the error occurs
{Do stuff with file}
{Do something else}

\end{document}
```

Sample my_tex_file.tex with content:

```
%% commented line
Actual text
```

Sample blank my_tex_file.tex:

```
%% Commented line
```

**The error I see is:**

```
<to be read again>
                  \setbox
l.106 ...ifthenelse{ \isFileEmpty{\filecontent }}

!  ==> Fatal error occured, no output PDF produced!
```

**References:**

I have been referencing https://archive.org/details/B-001-002-139/page/n383/mode/2up and https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_does_%5Cexpandafter_work:_An_introduction_to_TeX_tokens

**What I'm at:**
I believe I can use additional `\expandafter`s to get this to work, but I have been unsuccessful.  I understand the basic concept of `\expandafter` but I lack the experience to get this particular use case to work.

Any help getting this to work woudl be greatly appreciated.  Any alternatives to this method are also appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your `\isFileEmpty` macro is going to take `\expandafter` as its argument. Try putting `\expandafter` before `isFileEmpty` as well. Also, since you have the contents of the file in `\filecontent`, you can use the methods here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co to check for contents. Your solution will blow up if, e.g., there's a paragraph break in the input file.

Comment: @DonaldHosek Well, a `\par` in restricted horizontal mode does nothing. However there are several other things that may go wrong if tried in restricted horizontal mode.

Comment: What kind of contents do you expect in the files? Is it completely general or somehow restricted?

Comment: What about files not coding visible things but macro definitions and the like? What about files not coding paragraphs of text of a document but coding floats? (Floats (figures/tables) are visible only in case of there being a page where they occur=in case of being processed via output-routine.) What about files coding overfull boxes of height/width/depth 0pt containing other boxes with visible material? What about files where braces denote begin/end of scopes and thus don't need to be balanced and therefore can disturb `\CatchFileDef`? Files with `#` can be a problem for `\CatchFileDef`, too.

Comment: @DonaldHosek Thanks for inluding that link, I forgot to add that one.  That is one of the links I used to create the existing existing \isFileEmpty definition.  In isolation with the "Macro test line" above, the expected boolean is output.

Comment: @DonaldHosek changing the "broken" line to ```\ifthenelse{\expandafter\isFileEmpty\expandafter{\filecontent }}``` does not seem to have an effect

Comment: @egreg my expectation for the file is either a) "Empty": pure empty, newline only, or commented line only or b) "Content": text (there will always be plain text in the "content" option), tables, figures, possible macros

Comment: @UlrichDiez I'll run through the list.  There could be macros, but there would always be plain text also.  I do expect tables and figures, but there will also be text with those.  I am not familiar with this item but I can say there will be no explicit overfull definitions.  The file will be "self-containable" and will be balanced brackets with in.  While I have limited familiarity with ```\CatchFileDef``` (I discovered while trying to make this work), I have been testing with ```#``` comments and have been successful so far; what issues are you aware of with ```#``` and ```\CatchFileDef```?

Comment: @rmrf `#` is not for comments in LaTeX but is for denoting macro parameters. But you are right: `\CatchFileDef` treats `#` correctly. I confused this with some other package (everyhook) where this currently is not the case. I'm sorry about my statement about `#` and `\CatchFileDef` - that statement was my mistake.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I appologize, I am mixing languages in my head.

Comment: @rmrf Never mnind. ;-) In the same semester that I started learning TeX, I was also taught C ++ and SQL. What was twirling around in my head at that time makes no description possible ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\isFileEmpty`-test in your example seems to be intended to put into a box the things that got caught as a macro and to measure the width of that box and in case of that width being 0 to "assume" emptiness.

Such a test can be fooled/outmanoeuvred, e.g., by placing overfull boxes of depth/height/width 0pt containing displayable content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatch.tex}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\hbox{Hello, world!}\hbox{Hello, world!}\hbox{Hello, world!}}%
\wd\mybox=0pt %
\ht\mybox=0pt %
\dp\mybox=0pt %
\box\mybox
\end{filecontents*}

\newboolean{IsFileEmpty}%
\newcommand{\isFileEmpty}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1\unskip}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt%
    \setboolean{IsFileEmpty}{true}%
  \else
    \setboolean{IsFileEmpty}{false}%
  \fi
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{IsFileEmpty}}%
}%

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}
This is the result of the emptiness-test after catching the content
of the file \verb|filetocatch.tex| into the macro \verb|\filecontent|:

\CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{filetocatch.tex}{}%
\isFileEmpty{\filecontent}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\bigskip

This is the result of carrying out the macro \verb|\filecontent|:

\filecontent

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Floats might be a problem, too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatch.tex}
\begin{figure}[h]
This is a figure.
\caption{This is the figure's caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\newboolean{IsFileEmpty}%
\newcommand{\isFileEmpty}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1\unskip}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt%
    \setboolean{IsFileEmpty}{true}%
  \else
    \setboolean{IsFileEmpty}{false}%
  \fi
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{IsFileEmpty}}%
}%

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{filetocatch.tex}{}%

This is the result of carrying out the macro \verb|\filecontent|:

\filecontent

\bigskip

Carrying out the emptiness-test after catching the content
of the file \verb|filetocatch.tex| into the macro \verb|\filecontent|
leads to an error-message on the terminal/console:

\verb|! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.|

Subsequent error-messages follow.

Besides this you erroneously get as result:

\isFileEmpty{\filecontent}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Verbatim-material (`verbatim`-environments / `\verb|...|`-commands) will also be a problem for the `\isFileEmpty`-test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatch.tex}
\begin{verbatim}
This is verbatim
\end{verbatim}
\end{filecontents*}

\newboolean{IsFileEmpty}%
\newcommand{\isFileEmpty}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1\unskip}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt%
    \setboolean{IsFileEmpty}{true}%
  \else
    \setboolean{IsFileEmpty}{false}%
  \fi
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{IsFileEmpty}}%
}%

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{filetocatch.tex}{}%

% Carrying out the emptiness-test after catching the content
% of the file filetocatch.tex into the macro \filecontent
% leads to error-messages on the terminal/console.
% 
% \verb|! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.|
%
% Subsequent error-messages follow.
% 
% You get neither a result nor a proper output-file/.pdf-file 
% because LaTeX does not leave verbatim-mode and therefore 
% does not even find the \end{document}-directive.
%

\isFileEmpty{\filecontent}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\end{document}
```

---

In case you wish to know whether some characters other than space-characters and other than newline-characters (usually Return / CR or CR+LF) and other than lines preceded by `%` are in the file, you can switch to verbatim-catcode-régime and switch the integer-parameter `\endlinechar` to a negative value by means of `\CatchFileDef`'s third argument.

**This would not be a test for displayable content. This would be a test for content that can be tokenized for further processing by TeX which consists of things other than space-characters/linebreaks/empty lines/comment-lines.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{listings} % Used only for displaying files
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, 
        basicstyle=\ttfamily, language={}, frame=single}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatchA.tex}
This is some content.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatchB.tex}
% This is some comment



% This is some comment
  % 

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatchC.tex}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\vbox{%
                     \hbox{Hello, world!}%
                     \hbox{Hello, world!}%
                     \hbox{Hello, world!}%
                   }%
\wd\mybox=0pt %
\ht\mybox=0pt %
\dp\mybox=0pt %
\box\mybox
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatchD.tex}
\begin{figure}[h]
This is a figure.
\caption{This is the figure's caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatchE.tex}
{\def\empty{}\empty\empty\empty}%
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{filetocatchF.tex}
}}}}{{{
Unbalanced braces.
\end{filecontents*}


\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument contains no tokens/is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked contains no tokens/is
%%                       empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked contains some tokens/
%%                       is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
%% The way in which this macro works is explained in my answer to the
%% TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange-Question "Expandable test for an empty token
%% list—methods, performance, and robustness" at
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522506>
%% In that answer it is named \CheckWhetherEmpty.
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty/no tokens at all or only
%% explicit space tokens (character code 32/category code 10)):
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo#1{}.}%
}%

\newcommand{\isFileEmpty}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{#1}{%
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \catcode`\%=14 %
    \catcode`\ =10 %
    \catcode`\^^I=12 %
    \endlinechar=-1 %
  }%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherBlank
  \expandafter{\filecontent}%
}%
\makeatother

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}

This is the content of \verb|filetocatchA.tex|:

\lstinputlisting{filetocatchA.tex}

This is the result of the empty-test:

\isFileEmpty{filetocatchA.tex}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\leavevmode\hrule height .5\ht\strutbox\hfill

This is the content of \verb|filetocatchB.tex|:

\lstinputlisting{filetocatchB.tex}

This is the result of the empty-test:

\isFileEmpty{filetocatchB.tex}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\leavevmode\hrule height .5\ht\strutbox\hfill

This is the content of \verb|filetocatchC.tex|:

\lstinputlisting{filetocatchC.tex}

This is the result of the empty-test:

\isFileEmpty{filetocatchC.tex}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\leavevmode\hrule height .5\ht\strutbox\hfill

This is the content of \verb|filetocatchD.tex|:

\lstinputlisting{filetocatchD.tex}

This is the result of the empty-test:

\isFileEmpty{filetocatchD.tex}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\leavevmode\hrule height .5\ht\strutbox\hfill

This is the content of \verb|filetocatchE.tex|:

\lstinputlisting{filetocatchE.tex}

This is the result of the empty-test:

\isFileEmpty{filetocatchE.tex}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\leavevmode\hrule height .5\ht\strutbox\hfill

This is the content of \verb|filetocatchF.tex|:

\lstinputlisting{filetocatchF.tex}

This is the result of the empty-test:

\isFileEmpty{filetocatchF.tex}{File is empty!}{File is not empty!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough and well explained response.  I lighty tested both and they are working wonderfully.  I will implement verbatim-catcode-régime as that seems to cover every likely possibility that my use case would ever present, with the other option in reserve.

Comment: @rmrf I just added a link to my comment about `\UD@CheckWhetherNull` to the question [Expandable test for an empty token list—methods, performance, and robustness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513337)