# Using \if with an empty argument

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I'd like to modify a piece of code, namely Friedhelm Sowa's picinpar.sty.

There is the command

```
\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,#4]
```

which inserts a picture (#3) #1 lines below the start of a paragraph at position #2 with caption #4

In the picinpar.sty file this command is defined as

```
 \long\def\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,#4] {%
   \advance\c@figure -1
   \begin{window}[#1,#2,{#3},{\def\@captype{figure}%
    \wincaption#4\par}] %
  }
```

I do not explore here further, what the window-environment is about, it is irrelevant  for my question. What I'd like to achieve is an option that no caption is printed.
That works well, if I rewrite figwindow as

```
 \long\def\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,#4] {%
  \advance\c@figure -1
  \begin{window}[#1,#2,{#3},{}]%
 }
```

My idea was now to use a conditional that prints no caption if #4 is {} and prints a caption otherwise. My attempt was:

```
 \long\def\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,#4] {%
  \advance\c@figure -1
  \begin{window}[#1,#2,{#3},\if #4{} {} \else   {\def\@captype{figure}%
    \wincaption#4\par}\fi]
}
```

Which unfortunately does not work. It ends up in the else-branch, if I call

```
\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,{}]
```

or
\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,]

However modifying the style to comparing to a '*' instead to an empty token works perfectly:

```
\long\def\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,#4] {%
 \advance\c@figure -1
 \begin{window}[#1,#2,{#3},\if #4* {} \else {\def\@captype{figure}%
    \wincaption#4\par}\fi]
 }

\figwindow[#1,#2,#3,*]
```

Although I have a working solution, I'd prefer to make the {} one work (it appears more intuitive to me
Surprisingly

```
\newcommand{\Compare}[2]{#1  \if #2{} EMPTY \else --- #2 ---\fi\par}
\Compare{EMPTY}{}
\Compare{FILLED}{HOW?}
```

works as I'd expect its output is

> EMPTY   - EMPTY -

> FILLED  - HOW? -

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance right now

Comment: your working solution fails if #4 starts with eg xx. just use an empty argument not `{}` then `\ifx\relax#4\relax`

Comment: For better stability than what @DavidCarlisle suggests, you can also use `\if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax` (now only a really empty argument results in true).

Comment: For some more information on robustness and performance of ifempty-tests, this might be an interesting read (including the comments): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513337/117050

Answer (score 3):

`\if #2{}\else ...#2...\fi`

expands `#2` and compares the first two non expandable tokens so

if `#2` is `aabbcc` the true branch is taken and it expands to `bbcc{}`

if `#2` is `a` it compares `a` to `{` and takes the false branch, skipping over `}`

If `#2` is empty it compares `{` to `}` which is false

You can test for `#2` being empty with

`\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else ...#2...\fi`

as `\detokenize` never returns a command token that would test true with `\relax` (all non expandable command tokens test equal with `\if`) but if `#2` is empty this is `\if\relax\relax` which is true.

Comment: Thank you, David! That is the solution, indeed.